# How to speed up a recursive method written in Java

Tags: java, performance, recursion

This is a problem from LeetCode, I solve it using C++, but when I use the same type of method with Java, it returns a Time Limit Exceeded error. Does anyone know the reason?

Here's the problem:

> **Convert Sorted Array to Binary Search Tree. Given an array where elements are sorted in ascending order, convert it to a height balanced BST.**

And here's my solution written in Java:

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] num) {
        if(num.length == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return sub(num, 0, num.length-1);
        }
    }

    public TreeNode sub(int[] num, int start, int end) {
        int indexRoot = (start+end+1) / 2;
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(num[indexRoot]);

        if(indexRoot > start) {
            root.left = sub(num, 0, indexRoot-1);
        }
        if(indexRoot < end) {
            root.right = sub(num, indexRoot+1, end);
        }

        return root;
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can speed it up? Thanks.

Comment: What is the size of the array that you're working with?

Comment: Shoouldn't  `root.left = sub(num, 0, indexRoot-1);` be  `root.left = sub(num, start, indexRoot-1); `?

Comment: Yeah @cactus1 is right. The code your posted recurses infinitely. (which is probably why you're getting a timeout error)

Comment: Oops! Didnt find it out, thx a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just a typo in the code. The correct one should be as follow.

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] num) {
        if(num.length == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return sub(num, 0, num.length-1);
        }
    }

    public TreeNode sub(int[] num, int start, int end) {
        int indexRoot = (start+end+1) / 2;
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(num[indexRoot]);

        if(indexRoot > start) {
            root.left = sub(num, start, indexRoot-1);
        }
        if(indexRoot < end) {
            root.right = sub(num, indexRoot+1, end);
        }

        return root;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Organize own stack - Pairs of indexes. Instead of recoursively call the procedure use the stack placing pairs and invoke sub() for the topmost one.

```
while (stack of pairs processing is not finished) {
  //get next pair and process the pair
  sub(next pair);
}

public TreeNode sub(int[] num, int start, int end) {
    int indexRoot = (start+end+1) / 2;
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(num[indexRoot]);

    if(indexRoot > start) {
        root.left = addToStack(num, 0, indexRoot-1);
    }
    if(indexRoot < end) {
        root.right = addToStack(num, indexRoot+1, end);
    }

    return root;
}
```